Relative tense and absolute tense, is this how it’s determined?
相対テンス in 名詞修飾 is also true when it comes to アスペクト（テイル) or other forms like 〜てしまう, etc?
Regarding this post, there’s a reference here that helps people find out the tense of the sentence:
Reference: 初級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック
視点の原理
a. 主節と従属節 (名詞修飾節を含む) が同じ時制形式 (ル形－ル形、タ形－タ形) である時、従属節のテンスは発話時との時間的前後関係で決まる (=従属節のテンスも絶対テンスになる)。
b. 主節と従属節 (名詞修飾節を含む)が異なる時制形式 (ル形－タ形、タ形－ル形) である時、従属節のテンスは主節時との時間的前後関係で決まる (=従属節のテンスは相対テンスである)。
And I’m wondering is this actually true? Does this tell us what the tense of the relative sentence is relative to the overall sentence? Like a relative tense ends with る and the main clause ends with る、then does that mean the tense of the relative clause is relative to when I speak those words and if they’re the opposite, then does that mean that the relative tense is relative to the main clause? If both verbs end in the same tense, then is the same as english absolute tense? If they are the opposite, then only they are the Japanese relative tense, is this true? If there are three verbs in a sentence, and one relative clause’s tense is the same with the main clause, then what about the other relative clause? Is it relative to the main clause?

Isn't this just a roundabout logical way to say Japanese always has relative tense but since the past relative to the past is also absolutely in the past that that means that if both have the same tense the relative clause becomes absolute? This feels like more of a test of logic than anything.

For some reason my brain just can’t process relative tense and even now I’m not quite sure after some time thinking

I will provide a lengthlier actual answer explaining it then.

As I said in the comment, it seems to purely be a logical conclusion of that in Japanese subordinate clauses, the tense is always relative to the clause they're embedded in. Your comment indicates I need first explain this idea and difference.

食べている人を見ていた。 <-> “I was looking at someone who was eating.”

Note that the relative clause in English uses past tense, but in Japanese it uses nonpast. English uses absolute tense for subordinate clauses, meaning that the tense of all clauses is relative to the moment of speaking. Japanese uses relative tense for subordinate clause, the tense is relative to their matrix clause, and only the final clause has a tense relative to the moment of speaking, and not even that for Japanese has a historical present function where past events can be narrated with a nonpast tense provided the narrator sounds like he was there and experienced the event personally.
The point is that the person whom one saw was currently eating at the time of seeing, which is why nonpast is used, we can indeed also say:

“食べていた人を見いていた。” <-> “I was watching someone who was eating [before the time I saw him].

This sentence means that person had stopped eating already at the time the speaker saw him. At the time of seeing, one indeed saw a “食べていた人, if we put the entire sentence in nonpast, we get “食べていた人を見ている”. “I am looking at someone who was eating before.”. I suppose in this case English also allows some degree of relative tense in that the subordinate clause may indeed be past with a nonpast main clause, but never in reverse.
This applies to all sorts of things:

“昔は弟は可愛いと思ってた。” -> “I used to feel my younger brother was cute.”, again, at the time of thinking, his being cute going on at that very time so we use nonpast.
“食べたあとに寝る” -> “I will go to bed after I've eaten.”, a past tense used for a future event, because it takes place before going to bed, it is in the past relative to that. In fact, I don't think “食べるあとに” is ever used at all, by it's very nature “あと” meaning “after” implies what comes before it　must be in the past relative to it's matrix clause. “食べる前に” is the opposite and “食べた前に” doesn't really occur for this reason.
“お風呂に入るところだった。” -> “I was about to have a bath.” “るところ” is a set phrase that means “to be about to”. It doesn't matter whether one “is” or “was” about to, being about to happens in the future relative to the matrix clause, so “お風呂に入ったところ” always means “I just had a bath.”

This is what Japanese having relative tense means.
Now, as for why the subordinate clause becomes absolute when both tenses are the same, that's just a logical conclusion I guess of relative tense, to re-use the example of “食べていた人を見いていた。”. The main clause is in the past, and the subordinate clause is in the past relative to the past, it is thus by logical inference also in the past relative to the time of utterance and as such, one can say the tense effectively becomes absolute which is just another term for “relative to time of utterance”. The same applies to “食べている人を見ている”. It is nonpast relative to the nonpast, meaning that it's either in the now, or in the future, this in the absolute sense nonpast.
When both are mixed and matched, it becomes more complex. “食べたあとに寝る。” in fact in theory may have “食べた” lie in the absolute past. In theory, one can utter this sentence after one has already eaten I guess, though in practice it will be when one hasn't yet so in practice it will lie in the future but in theory it's indeterminate whether it lies in the past or not, it is however determined that it must lie in the past relative to “寝る”. Eating will always happen before going to bed in this sentence, in theory eating could already have happened.
I hope this answers your confusion.

Thanks, this really helped me a lot, I’ve been stumped for so long about relative tense but slowly I’m starting to get it, also I would like to ask is that can historical present be anywhere? Like not just the main verb of the sentence but in a relative clause? Also is it natural for highly educated explaining video to omit the tense of the main verb? I watch educative videos and I’ve seen that they leave out the tense of the main verb and start a completely new sentence. Is this natural? All of the cases I’ve seen are them omitting the た form but maybe that’s cause I’m watching history.

I'm firstly not sure how the tense of a verb can grammatically be ommitted at all. It's part of the ending. You might want to make a new topic about that with a specific example of what you meant. Historical present only applies to the main verb yes, subordinate verbs are always relative to the main verb so if the main verb be historical present, then the subordinates are still relative to that so future tense will be used for something in the future relative to the historical present, but in the past relative to the now.
